# TFS work item "Assigned To" field limited to actively selected team

Tags: tfs

Work items fields like "Assigned To" in TFS show way too many users by default. I understand I can limit this by editing the WIT to be more project or group specific like with the following:

```
<FieldDefinition name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
        <LISTITEM value="[project]\Contributors" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <HELPTEXT>The person currently working on this bug</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
```

This helps, but I'm using a structure where all projects are located in a single Team Project, so the user list is still much too large.

Is there a way to populate a string drop down (like "Assigned To") based on team, similar to how area and iteration paths populate based on what team you are creating work items under?

Answer (score 1):

No this kind of customisation is not possible with TFS.

Once you have your work broken down by area and iteration, it should be easy enough to view on the backlog when planning work who will take what and if anything is assigned to someone who's not on the team.